# On form submit required fields are not highlighted in red color

Tags: angular-ngmodel

New to angular4 again stuck up with new scenario. I have a form and inside that I have written a dialog content which goes like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCloseConfirm(f.value)">
  <md-dialog-content>
  <md-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="70px">
      <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput placeholder="App Name" value="{{ data.appName }}">
        </md-input-container>
      </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="App ID" value="{{ data.appID }} ">
          </md-input-container>
        </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput ngModel required name="customer" 
#customer="ngModel" placeholder="Customer" >
        </md-input-container>
      </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
  </md-dialog-content>
  </form>
  <md-dialog-actions>
    <button md-raised-button type="submit" class="saveBTN" >Save</button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
```

The problem is when I click on save, it should show the required fields in red color which isn't happening.

Comment: i didn't get the solution but now i know why it wasn't highlighted because as soon as this dialog is opened the first field gets autofocused and when i click on save it doesn't show the required fields in red color and if the cursor is on required field then i try to save and then it highlights the field in red color but this is not what i expected

Comment: can anyone suggest any idea ??